# Issues with ADS1015 and Orange Pi Zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, i2c

I am using the Orange Pi Zero and I need to read an analog sensor, so I connect the ADS1015 module through I2C to the board, the problem is when I install the library from github, I get the following error, which when I use with a raspberry works correctly

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/prueba/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/libgpiod_pin.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gpiod
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gpiod'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prueba.py", line 2, in <module>
    import board
  File "/root/prueba/lib/python3.8/site-packages/board.py", line 82, in <module>
    from adafruit_blinka.board.orangepi.orangepizero import *
  File "/root/prueba/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/board/orangepi/orangepizero.py", line 5, in <module>
    from adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.allwinner.h3 import pin
  File "/root/prueba/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/allwinner/h3/pin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from adafruit_blinka.microcontroller.generic_linux.libgpiod_pin import Pin
  File "/root/prueba/lib/python3.8/site-packages/adafruit_blinka/microcontroller/generic_linux/libgpiod_pin.py", line 5, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: libgpiod Python bindings not found, please install and try again! See https://github.com/adafruit/Raspberry-Pi-Installer-Scripts/blob/master/libgpiod.sh
```

The library comes from `https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ADS1x15`

and the file .py contain the code

```
import time
import board
import busio
import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1015 as ADS
from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in import AnalogIn

# Create the I2C bus
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

# Create the ADC object using the I2C bus
ads = ADS.ADS1015(i2c)

# Create single-ended input on channel 0
chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0)

# Create differential input between channel 0 and 1
#chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0, ADS.P1)

print("{:>5}\t{:>5}".format('raw', 'v'))

while True:
    print("{:>5}\t{:>5.3f}".format(chan.value, chan.voltage))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Search for information with the help of google but I could not find any solution to i can do the analog readings with the ADS1015 module and Orange Pi, if anyone has more information or can help me I would appreciate it.
PS: Lastly, to verify that the I2C bus detects the device, execute the command `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` and this is the result

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Comment: Did you install the library as the error message suggests?

Comment: I only installed ads1x15 library, i can see two different library board and gpiod, both are libraries for Raspberry